# How do i pass different strings into the same method?

Tags: c#, string, methods

I don't know if the title is technically correct but i'm trying to pass different strings into the same method at different times, let me explain:

When the user deletes their new account, this gets called:

```
RecordMetric(Constants.AccountDeleted, userId, String.Empty);
```

which will get passed through this method:

```
   internal static void RecordMetric(Constants Constant, long userid, string data, long? siteid)
   {
        MetricsSystemService.TrackEvent(Constants.AccountDeleted, 
                        new Dictionary<string, string> { { "userid", userid.ToString() }, { "data", data} }); 
   }
```

This sends the data to application insights which gives us an indication of how many users have deleted their account.

but what if i want to pass a different string through the method above, for example:

```
RecordMetric(Constants.PasspointReset, userId, String.Empty);
```

I could just create another method for it but that'll be inefficient, instead i want it to be passed through the same method as the AccountDeleted string.

I've tried making an string extension:

```
internal static class ConstantsString
    {
        internal static string ToConstantsString(this string input)
        {
            if (input == "SignupStart") return Constants.SignupStart;
            if (input == "SignupEnd") return Constants.SignupEnd;
            if (input == "LoginStart") return Constants.LoginStart;
            if (input == "LoginEnd") return Constants.LoginEnd;
            if (input == "AccountDeleted") return Constants.AccountDeleted;
            if (input == "PasspointReset") return Constants.PasspointReset;
            if (input == "ImageChange") return Constants.ImageChange;
            if (input == "LoginFailed") return Constants.LoginFailed;
            if (input == "SignupVerified") return Constants.SignupVerified;
            if (input == "LibraryImageUsed") return Constants.LibraryImageUsed;
            if (input == "DeveloperAccountCreated") return Constants.DeveloperAccountCreated;
            if (input == "DeveloperAccountEdited") return Constants.DeveloperAccountEdited;
            if (input == "DeveloperAccountDeleted") return Constants.DeveloperAccountDeleted;

            return String.Empty;
        }
    }
```

and passing through the string extension like so:

```
        MetricsSystemService.TrackEvent(ConstantsString.ToConstantsString(), 
            new Dictionary<string, string> { { "userid", userid.ToString() }, { "data", data} });
```

but i'm getting a error: "No overload for method 'ToConstantsString' takes 0 arguments."

Is there another way to do this? or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Why doesn't `RecordMetric(Constants.PasspointReset, userId, String.Empty);` work? It looks like `RecordMetric` takes `string`, `userid` and `string` parameters already.

Comment: It looks like you can do what you want to do without creating any new methods. Code such as `RecordMetric(Constants.AccountDeleted, userId, String.Empty);` should actually run.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how Extensionmethods work.

```
"SignupStart".ToConstantsString()
```

will return `Constants.SignupStart`.

This is what ExtensionMethods do.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clearly defined, because we don't get to know if your Constants value are exactly the same as the ones returned by your extension method.

To avoid that kind of step you could use an enum with all your different types instead, and eventually if you need a string you could get it from the enum element.

Back to your error, the reason of that error message is due to you calling the extension method not on a string, as it's expected in the signature, but on a class.

You might want to that on the parameter you get from the outer call:

```
stringInput.ToConstantsString()
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this ugly & unmaintenable `ifs` you may want to use reflection:

```
internal static class ConstantsString
{
    internal static string ToConstantsString(this string input)
    {
        try
        {
            Type t = typeof (Constants);
            return t.GetProperty(input).GetValue(t, null).ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "Error";
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like so:

```
Console.WriteLine("LibraryImageUsed".ToConstantsString());
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're reversing what constants are used for. The idea is to store a value in only one place and refer to it using a compiled property name or constant name. That way a string which could potentially change is only stored in one place.

What you're doing is the opposite. You're using a string input to return a constant.

You could (and should) replace this:

```
internal static class ConstantsString
{
    internal static string ToConstantsString(this string input)
    {
        if (input == "SignupStart") return Constants.SignupStart;
```

And anyplace where you call

```
var someString = "SignupStart".ToConstantsString();
```

just refer directly to `Constants.SignupStart` instead.

Sometimes strings which are not declared as constants are called "magic strings." In other words, you have to know the exact correct string to use. For example, if someone doesn't know that the string they need is "SignupStart", how do they find out? They would need to dig through the code to find it. Constants and enums reduce or eliminate that. You type `Constants.` and intellisense shows you the available options. You don't need to remember what that string is.

Ideally you want to avoid having those magic strings in your code. If you need to know a certain string value to retrieve a constant then it defeats the benefit of having a constant.

Constants also help you catch errors when compiling instead of at runtime. For example, your code can build if someone accidentally types "SignUpStart" instead of "SignupStart", but then it will fail at runtime and someone could go out of their mind trying to figure out why.